# SymbolicExpression - to string

Tags: f#

I'm using [RProvider](http://bluemountaincapital.github.io/FSharpRProvider/) in F# to calculate some statistics of my data. When I call R function it returns [SymbolicExpression type](http://bluemountaincapital.github.io/FSharpRProvider/passing-data.html) but it is really difficult to parse data from this type. In my code I count quantiles like this

```
let seq = R.seq(namedParams ["from", box 0;"to", box 1;"length", box 11;])
let quantiles = R.quantile(namedParams ["x", box dataWithoutNan1; "prob", box seq; "type", box 5;])
```

Then quantiles is of type SymbolicExpression.

```
val quantiles : SymbolicExpression =
            0%          10%          20%          30%          40%          50% 
0.000000e+00 3.203978e-03 5.366154e-03 1.101344e-02 8.259162e-02 4.533620e-01 
         60%          70%          80%          90%         100% 
1.278446e+00 2.706468e+00 4.927400e+00 1.141095e+01 8.944235e+02
```

SymbolicExpression type has member `Value`

```
let quantilesValue = quantiles.Value
```

and it is of type obj

```
val quantilesValue : obj =
  [|0.0; 0.003203978402; 0.00536615421; 0.01101343569; 0.08259161954;
    0.4533619823; 1.278445928; 2.706467538; 4.927399755; 11.41095162;
    894.4234507|]
```

What I trying to do is printing these values like

> 0.0; 0.003203978402; 0.00536615421; 0.01101343569; 0.08259161954;
>           0.4533619823; 1.278445928; 2.706467538; 4.927399755; 11.41095162;
>           894.4234507

I tried to cast these objects to Seq or to List but I was not able to do this.
Any idea how to get values from SymbolicExpression in some simple way?

Comment: Looks like it is an Array. Could be casted to Seq though. Does `Seq.cast<float> quantilesValue`  work?

Comment: I tried it but it returns error `FS0001: The type 'obj' is not compatible with the type 'Collections.IEnumerable'`

Comment: The documentation says there is a `GetValue<'T>` extension method that can be used to convert `SymbolicExpression` to `double[]`.  Maybe that's what you need?

Comment: I tried it as well but I called it like .GetValue<seq<double>>() it threw an error that it has no converter for this type... but when I call it with .GetValue<double[]>() it finally works :)

Answer (score 1):

These code works for this issue

```
let quantiles = R.quantile(namedParams ["x", box dataWithoutNan1; "prob", box seq; "type", box 5;]).GetValue<double[]>()
```

or

```
let quantiles = R.quantile(namedParams ["x", box dataWithoutNan1; "prob", box seq; "type", box 5;]).GetValue<list<double>>()
```